# Apex Create Task says success but database has no new record

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I tried to create a task through apex. The test job says it was successful. However, when I exported data from the Task there are no additional rows. I can't tell if anything is wrong from the debug log. There is no customized validation rule on the Task. Please help and provide an approach to troubleshoot this situation in SalesForce environment.

Here's the test code:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true) class HelloWorldTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateHelloWorld() {

       Task newTask = new Task(Description = 'test task',
                                    Priority = 'Normal', 
                                    Status = 'Not Started', 
                                    Subject = 'Other', 
                                    WhoId = '003P000000dnR35IAE',
                                    WhatId = '001P000000Zc5G6',
                                    Type = 'Internal Action',
                                    ActivityDate = system.today());             
       insert newTask;


    }
}
```

Here's the debug log:

```
26.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
13:24:30.080 (80288000)|EXECUTION_STARTED
13:24:30.080 (80360000)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01pP00000000ziy|HelloWorldTestClass.validateHelloWorld
13:24:30.080 (80837000)|METHOD_ENTRY|[2]|01pP00000000ziy|HelloWorldTestClass.HelloWorldTestClass()
13:24:30.080 (80852000)|METHOD_EXIT|[2]|HelloWorldTestClass
13:24:30.102 (102146000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[15]|System.today()
13:24:30.102 (102204000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[15]|System.today()
13:24:30.102 (102294000)|DML_BEGIN|[23]|Op:Insert|Type:Task|Rows:1
13:24:30.115 (115312000)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|APXTConga4
13:24:30.215 (215194000)|DML_END|[23]
13:24:30.267 (215259000)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
13:24:30.267|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 1 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 1 out of 10000
  Number of code statements: 2 out of 200000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 10
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of fields describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of record type describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of child relationships describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of picklist describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 10
13:24:30.267|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|APXTConga4|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Number of code statements: 2 out of 200000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 10
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of fields describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of record type describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of child relationships describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of picklist describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 10
13:24:30.267|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END
13:24:30.215 (215338000)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|HelloWorldTestClass.validateHelloWorld
13:24:30.215 (215346000)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Answer (score 1):

test cases never commit their database transaction, so you won't have any visibility to this record outside of your test code.

Comment: I have @isTest(SeeAllData=true) at the beginning of the class. It should allow test method to access the database. I have also tried this in the real nontesting class and it's not work. The problem seems not related to testing. 
But still thanks much for the response.

Comment: SeeAllData lets the test access existing data, it says nothing about whether changes made in the test will be committed.

Comment: @isTest(SeeAllData=true)  is a bad practice as it looks for records in your org and fetches them, this can reach governor limits and also if the class gets migrated and the records are not there... testing fails.